# Is comparing equality on two pointers that are not in the same array defined behaviour?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Consider please

```
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int* pa = &a;
    int* pb = &b;

    int e = pa == pb;
}
```

Is this well-defined? `pa` and `pb` are not pointing to elements in the same array.

Comment: Yes, it is defined. Not sure if it's useful.

Comment: @DyZ: With respect, only a bit more fluff is going to convince me ;-)

Comment: Apparently the equality operator `==` is defined in a separate section from the "relational operators". For which it would be undefined.

Comment: A pointer to a variable is always defined, as long as the variable is in the scope. It is always possible to compare two defined pointers. Therefore..  But let me ask differently: why wouldn't the comparison be defined?

Comment: Well-defined.  Never any doubt about it.  It's the *relational* operations on pointers that have to be on pointers to within the same object.

Comment: In this case, both `a,b` are not initialized nor assigned.  It that relevant to your investigative question? (IMO, it does not change the "yes" answer.)

Comment: @chux No it isn’t. I wanted to present it in as minimal a fashion as possible and, perhaps, to make me look less of a charlatan than I really am ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I may quote the [c11](/questions/tagged/c11) standard: [§6.5.9¶2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9) Constraints regarding `==`:

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
> - one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void; or
> - one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.

So yes as per this - your code is well-formed. This is *well defined* (why? Because  the ***[standard doesn't mention](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9p6)*** in any form that comparing two unrelated pointer for **equality** is undefined behavior (All the accessing the element is not. Footnote-109)).<sup>1</sup>

Here is what it says in [§6.5.9¶6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9p6)

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space

<sup>1)The linked section( §6.5.9¶6 )is the one describing when two pointers compared using `==` is equal. By law, now we can say all other cases are not equal.
 No claims made regarding those that of other than one specified not being well defined.</sup>

---

To clarify a bit - the rules for relational operator is quite different from that of an equality operator. The section [§6.5.8¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p5) (Semantics of relational operators)

> When two pointers are compared, the result depends on the relative locations in the address space of the objects pointed to. .. ***In all other cases, the behavior is undefined***.

clearly mentions this - that to be even comparable - they have to follow the criteria pointed above. So using relational operator over two unrelated pointer will yield undefined behavior.

---

#### Extended discussion:

There is one more thing to clarify - *Constraints* and *semantics* are completely different thing. In case of standard for the operators - it first provides the constraints that must hold but it is just one side of the coin. What about the semantics? The standard mentioned about it after that. Now when originally answered, this answer focused on too much of constraints and not the semantics. Why is this important? We get to know that when we look into the relational operators. Check it's constraints -

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have real type; or
> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible object types.

Only by looking into this *constraints* - one may say `ptr < NULL` is well defined. Well it is not - and it is getting clear from the semantics specially from the point [§6.5.8¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.8p5). But surely `ptr < NULL` is well formed because it goes by what the constraints imposed on it.

Answer (score 7):

This behavior is well defined.

Section 6.5.9 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Equality Operators (`==`, `!=`) states the following:

> *2* One of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - **both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types**;
> - one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void ;or
> - one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.
>
> ...
>
> *5* Otherwise, at least one operand is a pointer.  If one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant, the null pointer
>   constant is converted to the type of the pointer.  If one  operand  is
>   a  pointer  to  an  object  type  and  the  other  is  a  pointer  to 
>   a  qualified  or unqualified version of void , the former is converted
>   to the type of the latter.
>
> *6* **Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object
>   and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to
>   one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a
>   pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a
>   pointer to the start of a different array  object  that  happens  to 
>   immediately  follow  the  first  array  object  in  the  address
>   space.**

Per paragraph 2, it doesn't require that the two pointers point to the same object, only that the types are compatible or at least one of them is either a `void *` or `NULL`.  Paragraph 6 subsequently states what it means for two pointers to compare equal.

This differs from section 6.5.8, which concerns Relational Operators (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`), which do not allow comparisons between unrelated objects, even if the types are the same:

> *5* **When  two  pointers  are  compared,  the  result  depends  on  the  relative  locations  in  the address space of the objects pointed to.** 
>   If two pointers to object types both point to the same  object,  or 
>   both  point  one  past  the  last  element  of  the  same  array 
>   object,  they compare  equal.   If  the  objects  pointed  to  are 
>   members  of  the  same  aggregate  object, pointers  to  structure 
>   members  declared  later  compare  greater  than  pointers  to 
>   members declared  earlier  in  the  structure,  and  pointers  to 
>   array  elements  with  larger  subscript values compare greater than
>   pointers to elements of the same array with lower subscript values.
>   All  pointers  to  members  of  the  same  union  object  compare 
>   equal.   If  the expression P points  to  an  element  of  an  array 
>   object  and  the  expression Q points  to  the last element of the
>   same array object, the pointer expression Q+1 compares greater than P
>   .  **In all other cases, the behavior is undefined**

Here, it states how two pointers pointing inside the same array objects are compared, and that the behavior is undefined in all other cases.  Section 6.5.9 does *not* have such wording.

On a side note, given the following:

```
char a[5], b[5];
```

6.5.9p6 could allow `a + 5 == b` to evaluate to true if `a` is immediately followed in memory by `b`.

Comment: ..and _that_ I doubt (your last statement). _All_ pointers can be compared for equality, independent of the type they point to. In the 3rd bullet quoted, both can be void pointers.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Good point.  Added a note that `void *` and `NULL` comparisons are also allowed.